# strange "Index exceeds matrix dimensions." matlab error

Tags: matlab

I've written this simple function on Matlab:

```
function [A] = tries (a, b, c, d)
    global S CdM AdA
    D = @(Z, Vx, Vy, Vz) 0.5*S*(Vx.^2 + Vy.^2 + Vz.^2)*CdM(sqrt(Vx.^2 + Vy.^2 + Vz.^2))*AdA(Z);
    A = D(a, b, c, d);
end
```

but I keep getting this error:
"Index exceeds matrix dimensions"
and it says that the error is in line 3.

When I put the same text in the main function (and not in a separate one) it works perfectly. 
Anything in mind what the problem might be?

Comment: Try using the [debugger](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html), and set a breakpoint at line 3.

Comment: with what parameters are you calling `tries`?

Answer (score 0):

The only item with index in line 3 is

```
AdA(Z)
```

that reading the function should be equal to `AdA(a)`. So Z is useless.

```
D2 = @(Vx, Vy, Vz) 0.5*S*(Vx.^2 + Vy.^2 + Vz.^2)*CdM(sqrt(Vx.^2 + Vy.^2 + Vz.^2));
A = D2(b, c, d)*AdA(a);
```

but, ignoring what AdA is and where Z (that is equal to a) comes from, try to force your function to display dimensions in order to see if they should match when the function is called.

```
disp(size(AdA));
disp(a);
```